# Dúvida com um erro no Angular - angular.js:13550 Error: Could not resolve

Tags: angularjs

Estou estudando como consumir WebApi com Angular por este [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par). Tudo estava indo bem até dar este erro:

`angular.js:13550 Error: Could not resolve 'stateOne' from state ''
    at Object.v.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at Object.v.go (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at angular-ui-router.min.js:7
    at angular.js:19157
    at e (angular.js:5869)
    at angular.js:6145`

Tentei pesquisar algo do tipo mas não encontrei uma explicação.
Pelo que pesquisei parece que isso é um problema ao carregar arquivos javascript.

Segue o código do módulo da aplicação:

```
// Módulo da aplicação

var AwesomeAngularMVCApp = angular.module('AwesomeAngularMVCApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

// Controllers
AwesomeAngularMVCApp.controller('LandingPageController', LandingPageController);
AwesomeAngularMVCApp.controller('LoginController', LoginController);
AwesomeAngularMVCApp.controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

// Factories
AwesomeAngularMVCApp.factory('LoginFactory', LoginFactory);
AwesomeAngularMVCApp.factory('RegistrationFactory', RegistrationFactory);
AwesomeAngularMVCApp.factory('AuthHttpResponseInterceptor', AuthHttpResponseInterceptor);

var configFunction = function ($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
          .state('stateOne', {
              url: '/stateOne?donuts',
              views: {
                  "containerOne": {
                      templateUrl: '/routesDemo/one'
                  },
                  "containerTwo": {
                      templateUrl: function (params) {
                          return '/routesDemo/two?donuts=' + params.donuts;
                      }
                  }
              }
          })
        .state('stateTwo', {
            url: '/stateTwo',
            views: {
                "containerOne": {
                    templateUrl: '/routesDemo/one'
                },
                "containerTwo": {
                    templateUrl: '/routesDemo/three'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('stateThree', {
            url: '/stateThree?donuts',
            views: {
                "containerOne": {
                    templateUrl: function (params) {
                        return '/routesDemo/two?donuts=' + params.donuts;
                    }
                },
                "containerTwo": {
                    templateUrl: '/routesDemo/three'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('loginRegister', {
            url: '/loginRegister?returnUrl',
            views: {
                "containerOne": {
                    templateUrl: '/Account/Login',
                    controller: LoginController
                },
                "containerTwo": {
                    templateUrl: '/Account/Register',
                    controller: RegisterController
                }
            }
        });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthHttpResponseInterceptor');
}
configFunction.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider'];
```

Segue o código do controller:

```
var LandingPageController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.models = {
        helloAngular: 'Eu consigo!'
    };

    $scope.product = {
        produto: 'Rotas'
    };

    $scope.navbarProperties = {
        isCollapsed: true
    };
}

/* The $inject property of every controller (and pretty much every other type of object in Angular) 
 * needs to be a string array equal to the controllers arguments, only as strings
**/
LandingPageController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Ficarei muito grato por alguma explicação em como resolver este erro.

Comment: O estado `stateOne` não foi configurado. Pode ser que esteja sendo definido em um arquivo .js que não foi carregado.

Comment: @OnoSendai Como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: Poste seu código. É difícil deduzir a causa real apenas pela mensagem de erro.